# Java - validate that a given string represents a Date, i.e. "YYYY-MM-DD"?

Tags: java, validation, date, datetime

User gives me a String that should represent expire date with the format of "yyyy-mm-dd".

I want to validate whether it's a date or not, and that's how I do it:

```
try { 
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
    System.out.println("Validating " + date + " as date");
    df.parse(date);
} 
catch (ParseException ex) { 
    // not yyyy-mm-dd date.
    System.out.println(": Bad");
    out.println(date + " cannot be parsed as a date. format: yyyy-mm-dd.");
    return;
}
```

If user gives me `"2014-02-02gy."`,

Then it prints: `"Validating 2014-02-02gy. as date"`

i.e. exception has not been thrown.

Why? and how can I validate a date? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Used regular expression as one of the comentters suggestion:

```
if (!date.matches("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}")  {
    out.println("Not a date"); 
}
```

Comment: If it's following a strict format (yyyy-mm-dd), I suppose you could use a regular expression to do a quick validity test.

Comment: Note that Month is `M`.

Comment: You could use a regex: `"2014-02-02".matches("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}")` but this would also give true for something like `"2013-31-31"`.

Comment: If you can parse out an unambiguous date, why do you care if there's extra garbage?

Comment: @Dmitri Because the extra garbage is not part of a valid date: it may lead to silent non-failure of input that *should* fail (as per the OPs request).

Comment: @user2864740: don't really see how, in this case. SDF is pretty brittle to begin with, being tolerant in the face of user garbage usually leads to a better experience. Would be much more useful to validate that the date you end up parsing makes sense in the context.

Comment: @Dmitri The programmer gets to define the contract (only limited by the systems/protocols that they must themselves interface with or conform to). The OP is clearly asking that this case is rejected. End of discussion. (Although there are many reasons to be *strict* when parsing input, IMOHO.)

Comment: @Jaxo Note that `20144-02-02` is a valid date, but would fail the pattern match (at least the one I think you were proposing).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Well, I'm sure more of mankind will be dead and the Earth floating in two pieces by the time the human race reaches the year 9999 ;)

Comment: @Jaxo I'm not sure of that - but *I* won't care ;-)

Comment: @user2864740: well, dear me, I almost tried to discuss something other than the trivial solution - lucky you were here to put a stop to it!

Comment: @Dmitri Such a "trivial solution" *ignores* what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @user2864740: I was talking about the already proposed trivial solutions, not offering one. In any case, OP obviously doesn't care, so the only question is: what's it to you?

Comment: @Dmitri So the OPs requirements matter .. glad we agree on that. And yes, there are sufficient answer.

Comment: actually, this seems to be a pretty nasty DateFormat bug. Most developers will probably expect to get an exception if the date has more chars than expected in the pattern. IMO

Answer (score 5):

You could always reverse the parse with a format to see if what you end up with is what you started with.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
String after = df.format(df.parse(date));
if (after.equals(date)) {
    // validated
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From the doc of `DateFormat.parse`

```
 * Parses text from the beginning of the given string to produce a date.
 * The method may not use the entire text of the given string.
 * <p>
 * See the {@link #parse(String, ParsePosition)} method for more information
 * on date parsing.
 *
 * @param source A <code>String</code> whose beginning should be parsed.
 * @return A <code>Date</code> parsed from the string.
 * @exception ParseException if the beginning of the specified string
 *            cannot be parsed.
```

*"if the beginning of the specified string cannot be parsed."* - it parses from the start until it gets the date it needs. So the `gy` is removed from the example you showed.

To fix:

```
String date = "2014-02-02gy";
try { 
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
    System.out.println("Validating " + date + " as date");
    Date dateObject = df.parse(date);
    if(!df.format(dateObject).equals(date))
        throw new ParseException(date, 0);
} catch (ParseException ex) { // not yyyy-mm-dd date.
    System.out.println(": Bad");
    System.out.println(date + " cannot be parsed as a date. format: yyyy-mm-dd.");
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note the javadoc of `SimpleDateFormat#parse(string)` which says

> The method may not use the entire text of the given string.

I don't believe you will be able to validate the characters at the end of your `String` this way. Note that the date is valid. You just want to check that a String matches a certain pattern.

Comment: Okay, a relevant comment. So how to solve the problem? Is this behavior affected by "set lenient"?

Comment: @user2864740 It doesn't seem like it. Not with `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: @Nadrendion I mean, setting lenient flag to `false` doesn't change the fact that the trailing characters are ignored.

Comment: If you want to work with dates try jodatime library.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not committed to use Java standard libraries, take a look at [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). The library is much more evolved than standard Java Dates. The piece of code for your case becomes as easy and clean as:

```
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
...
try {
  DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
  System.out.println("Validating " + date + " as date");
  formatter.parseDateTime(date);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
  System.out.println(": Bad");
  System.out.println(date + " cannot be parsed as a date. format: yyyy-mm-dd.");
  return;
}
...
```

On the other hand, if you have to stick to standard Java, I would go for [ns47731's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21054857/642706) or [Chris Gerken's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21054848/642706) solutions (which are roughly equivalent, my preference for Chris but that is personal taste).

Answer (score 0):

I used the following regular expression in order to validate a date:

```
if(!date.matches("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}")  {
      out.println("Not a date"); 
 }
```

Thanks for everyone that commented or answered :)

Comment: pay attention with this since it allows dates like "2012-13-01", which in truth will be converted into "2013-01-01"

Comment: @mardavi I know it's not perfect, but the user how enters this is a moderator , so I not performing a strict check

Answer (score 0):

Since DateFormat strangely matches only the start of the string (seems like a bug for me but it's documented, so well..), I'd explicitly add an end delimiter, like this

```
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd,");
    String date = "2014-02-02,";
    System.out.println("Validating " + date  + " as date");
    df.parse(date);
```